# Issues with CSS3 Animation with Firefox (slight artifacts) and Safari (not visible)?

Tags: html, css, firefox, safari

Having an issue with my CSS3 animation in Firefox and Safari. It works like a charm in Chrome and Internet Explorer. Spent a while attempting to figure this out myself, but no success. I followed all of the rules I could find, but I must be missing something.

**HTML**

```
<div class="background">
<div id="canvas" class="loading"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
    .background {
    background:#333;
    padding-bottom: 140px;
    padding-top: 65px;
}
#canvas.loading {
    -webkit-animation: animate 1.5s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation: animate 1.5s linear infinite;
    animation: animate 1.5s linear infinite;
    clip: rect(0, 80px, 80px, 40px);
    height: 80px;
    width: 80px;
    position:absolute;
    left:45%;
}
@-webkit-keyframes animate {
    0% {
        transform: rotate(0deg)
    }
    100% {
        transform: rotate(220deg)
    }
}
@keyframes animate {
    0% {
        transform: rotate(0deg)
    }
    100% {
        transform: rotate(220deg)
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes animate {
    0% {
        transform: rotate(0deg)
    }
    100% {
        transform: rotate(220deg)
    }
}
#canvas.loading:before {
    -webkit-animation: animate2 1.5s ease-in-out infinite;
    -moz-animation: animate 1.5s linear infinite;
    animation: animate2 1.5s ease-in-out infinite;
    clip: rect(0, 80px, 80px, 40px);
    content:'';
    border-radius: 50%;
    height: 80px;
    width: 80px;
    position:absolute
}
@-webkit-keyframes animate2 {
    0% {
        box-shadow: inset #5AA0E7 0 0 0 17px;
        transform: rotate(-140deg);
    }
    50% {
        box-shadow: inset #5AA0E7 0 0 0 2px;
    }
    100% {
        box-shadow: inset #5AA0E7 0 0 0 17px;
        transform: rotate(140deg);
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes animate2 {
    0% {
        box-shadow: inset #5AA0E7 0 0 0 17px;
        transform: rotate(-140deg);
    }
    50% {
        box-shadow: inset #5AA0E7 0 0 0 2px;
    }
    100% {
        box-shadow: inset #5AA0E7 0 0 0 17px;
        transform: rotate(140deg);
    }
}
@keyframes animate2 {
    0% {
        box-shadow: inset #5AA0E7 0 0 0 17px;
        transform: rotate(-140deg);
    }
    50% {
        box-shadow: inset #5AA0E7 0 0 0 2px;
    }
    100% {
        box-shadow: inset #5AA0E7 0 0 0 17px;
        transform: rotate(140deg);
    }
}
```

Here is the JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/myo4r9kk/

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It appears to work in FF for me. What version are you using?

Comment: @JoshCrozier Using Firefox 35. Here is the problem I'm having with artifacts: http://i.imgur.com/vb77mAo.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works for me in FF 35, can't say more than that.

Safari needs the `transform` property to be prefixed, so changing your css to the following will make it work (only included the relevant parts):

```
@-webkit-keyframes animate {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg)
        transform: rotate(0deg)
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(220deg)
        transform: rotate(220deg)
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes animate2 {
    0% {
        box-shadow: inset #5AA0E7 0 0 0 17px;
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-140deg);
        transform: rotate(-140deg);
    }
    50% {
        box-shadow: inset #5AA0E7 0 0 0 2px;
    }
    100% {
        box-shadow: inset #5AA0E7 0 0 0 17px;
        -webkit-transform: rotate(140deg);
        transform: rotate(140deg);

    }
}
```

It's probably best to change your `@keyframes` in the same way, just in case Safari one day supports unprefixed `@keyframes` but still needs prefixed `transform` rule.

And one last thing: It is generally considered safest to put the prefixed versions of a property before the standard version. I'm not totally sure but I guess that applies to keyframes as well, so you might want to put your `@-moz-keyframes` before your `@keyframes`. That may even solve your problems with Firefox (assuming a working implementation of the standard gets overwritten by a buggy version because you put the prefixed after the standard.

I took the liberty to update your fiddle with all those changes: http://jsfiddle.net/myo4r9kk/2/

**EDIT**

I just found this in your code:

```
-webkit-animation: animate2 1.5s ease-in-out infinite;
-moz-animation: animate 1.5s linear infinite;
animation: animate2 1.5s ease-in-out infinite;
```

Maybe that explains the problems with Firefox, are you by any chance testing this on FF < 15? In any case that `-moz-animation` should be the same as the other two.

Comment: I discovered that the animation just doesn't work on the Windows version of Safari (use it for testing), but it works fine on the Mac Safari.

I can't believe I didn't notice that issue in the code for Firefox, I remedied it! But it's sadly still resulting in the same choppy animation and artifacts (http://i.imgur.com/vb77mAo.png). I am using Firefox 35.0. Does that animation work fine on your Firefox?

Comment: I checked on another computer and it seems like the firefox artifacts are excluse to my machine. I'll leave it at that for now, thanks for your help. If you do end up thinking of anything that could be the reason for the performance I'm getting on my PC, I'm all ears.